# Comparing two SQL tables with identical columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare the "Revenue" field between two tables that have identical columns while being summarized using the SUM and GROUP BY clause. I only want to compare companies and products that exist in both tables.

For each table I have summarized:

```
SELECT Company,Product,Geography,Sum(Revenue) FROM GeographyA Group by 1,2,3
SELECT Company,Product,Geography,Sum(Revenue) FROM GeographyB Group by 1,2,3
```

This is the Code I have so far:

```
SELECT Company,Product,Geography,Sum(Revenue)
FROM GeographyA Group by 1,2,3
INNER JOIN GeographyB
ON GeographyA.Company = GeographyB.Company;
```

But I get an error saying "unexpected inner".

I want the result to be:

```
Company   Product     Revenue  Geography
ABC       Earphones   $500     A
ABC       Earphones   $700     B
BA        Fruits      $30      A
BA        Fruits      $40      B
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my joining code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: group by goes at the end of the statement. Also company, product, geography, and revenue are all ambiguous. Which table's company, product, geography, and revenue are you selecting and grouping by? If you want to treat them as one table (a strong hint they should be one table) you probably need a [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) instead of a join.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your SQL requests always with the DBMS you want an answer for.

Comment: Your "group by" is in the wrong place, hence the error.  Please specify *WHICH* database you're using (MSSQL? Oracle? Other?).  Please look at Thorsten Kettner's excellent response below, and "upvote" and/or "accept" if you found it helpful.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using Snowflake as the DBMS

Answer (score 1):

- You want to look at aggregations, so the first step is to aggregate both tables.
- You only want to look at companies and products that exist in both tables. You can check this with an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause.
- There may be rows for a company and product and geography that exist in only one of the two tables. Use a full outer join to show this. Use `COALESCE` to turn the null into a zero.

The complete query in standard SQL (you haven't told us your DBMS, so this is the best I can offer, you may have to make little adjustments, so it works in your DBMS):

```
WITH a AS
(
  SELECT company, product, geography, SUM(revenue) as total
  FROM geographya
  WHERE (company, product) IN (SELECT company, product FROM geographyb)
  GROUP BY company, product, geography
)
, b AS
(
  SELECT company, product, geography, SUM(revenue) as total
  FROM geographyb
  WHERE (company, product) IN (SELECT company, product FROM geographya)
  GROUP BY company, product, geography
)
SELECT
  company, product, geography,
  COALESCE(a.total, 0) as a_total,
  COALESCE(b.total, 0) as b_total
FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN b USING (company, product, geography)
ORDER BY company, product, geography;
```

If you want separate rows, as shown in your example (which would make the comparison a tad more more difficult for a human reader), then use `UNION ALL`:

```
(
  SELECT company, product, geography, SUM(revenue) as total, 'A' as source
  FROM geographya
  WHERE (company, product) IN (SELECT company, product FROM geographyb)
  GROUP BY company, product, geography
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT company, product, geography, SUM(revenue) as total, 'B' as source
  FROM geographyb
  WHERE (company, product) IN (SELECT company, product FROM geographya)
  GROUP BY company, product, geography
)
ORDER BY company, product, geography, source;
```